# Componente select com ng-model, relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: angularjs, html5, html-select

Tenho um componente select

```
<div  class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Município:</label> 
        <select ng-model="distrito.entidade.id.municipio.id.nome"  class="form-control"  >
            <option value="{{mun.id}}"  ng-repeat="mun in municipios " >{{mun.nome}}</option>   
        </select>
</div>
```

e quero trazer o nome do município que está dentro da tabela município esta dentro da tabela entidade que está relacionado com a tabela distrito onde fica o componente.

PS: A informação ta chegando corretamente do controller.js da tela pois foi feito o debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui Solucionar mudando o `value` e o `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Município:</label>
        <select ng-model="distrito.entidade.municipio.id" class="form-control">
            <option value="{{dis.idEntidade.idMunicipio.id}}" ng-repeat="dis in distritos">{{dis.idEntidade.idMunicipio.nome}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```